# SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration(DTD)

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

I'm trying to understand ws-security signing and encryption. I've followed [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws5/index.html) guide. As mentioned I've Installed rampart, have created the relevant `*.aar` file successfully and deployed it in the tomcat servlet engine, added the `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` Bouncy Castle security provider (necessary for the public-key cryptography features used in the example code) to JVM security configuration (the `lib/security/java.security` file), added the Bouncy Castle JAR  to both  Axis2 installation's lib directory and  Axis2 server application's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. (Which is the setup to run the given sample) But when running the example described, I am getting the following errors

```
 [java] Connecting to http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/library-signencr
 [java] Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration(DTD)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:123)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
 [java]     at com.sosnoski.ws.library.adb.LibrarySignencrStub.getBook(LibrarySignencrStub.java:205)
 [java]     at com.sosnoski.ws.library.adb.WebServiceClient.main(WebServiceClient.java:83)
 [java] Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration(DTD)
 [java]     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createDTD(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:455)
 [java]     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:282)
 [java]     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:198)
 [java]     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
 [java]     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:686)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
 [java]     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
 [java]     ... 7 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: And when you open this http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ link in browser, what do you see?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with a webservice that has always worked but yesterday. That problem went out because in the code we wait an xml response but it gave an html error page. So the DOCUMENT TYPE (html page) was not what we expected in the code. And all of this happened because the server moved away!

Sorry for answer so late, but I hope my answer will help another person in the future ^-^